# how to decrease the time to send bulk APNS in php

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

i am using the below code to send APNS. It's work fine for one device, when the device are more(for example 1000) it takes too much time. How can it is optimized. Please help me.

my code

```
function apnsNotification($deviceIds, $msg )
{
$message = json_encode($msg);
$passphrase = '1234';
$payload = json_encode([
'aps' => [
'alert' => $message,
'module'=> $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 1
]
]);
$result = 'Start' . '<br />';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'sampleapp_apns_12.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
echo count($deviceIds) . ' devices will receive notifications.<br />';
foreach ($deviceIds as $item)
{
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . '<br />');
} else {
echo 'Apple service is online.' . '<br />';
}
$data = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $item) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$result = fwrite($fp, $data, strlen($data));
if (!$result)
{
echo 'Undelivered message count: ' . $item . '<br />';
}
else 
{
echo 'Delivered message count: ' . $item . '<br />';
}
if ($fp) 
{
fclose($fp);
echo 'The connection has been closed by the client' . '<br />';
}
}
echo count($deviceIds) . ' devices have received notifications.<br />';
}
```